# How to bring back a deleted tab in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I accidentally deleted data tab in visual studio 2010 design mode. How can i bring it back??

Comment: Surely you mean 'closed' and not 'deleted'

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve any window under the `View` tab in VS, you're probably looking for the `Solution Explorer`

EDIT:
Right-click in your toolbox and select `Show all` or `Reset toolbox`

Comment: @ Rob .....I mean the data tab of toolbox. It is deleted .How can i restore it back??

Comment: I got it.......we need to rightclick the toolbox and then select **reset toolbox.............**:)